# IOS drawing a simple image turns out blurry using Xamarin C#

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, blurry, uigraphicscontext

I'm developing in Xamarin and would like to draw a simple circle with the text "CIRCLE" inside it and display that image in a UIImageView. The problem is that the circle and text appear very blurry. I've read a bit about subpixels but I don't think that's my problem.

Here's the blurry image and code, hoping someone has some ideas :)

```
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (new SizeF(150,150));
var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();

var content = "CIRCLE";
var font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize (16);

const float width = 150;
const float height = 150;

context.SetFillColorWithColor (UIColor.Red.CGColor);
context.FillEllipseInRect (new RectangleF (0, 0, width, height));

var contentString = new NSString (content);
var contentSize = contentString.StringSize (font);

var rect = new RectangleF (0, ((height - contentSize.Height) / 2) + 0, width, contentSize.Height);

context.SetFillColorWithColor (UIColor.White.CGColor);
new NSString (content).DrawString (rect, font, UILineBreakMode.WordWrap, UITextAlignment.Center);

var image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
imageView.Image = image;
```

[image: Blurry Circle]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason why it's blurry is because it was resized. That bitmap is not 150x150 (like the context you created), it's 333x317 pixels.

It could be because `imageView` is scaling it's image (there's no source code) or because of pixel doubling (for retina displays). In the later case what you really want to use is:

```
UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions (size, false, 0);
```

which will (using `0`) automagically use the right scaling factor for retina (or not) display - and look crisp (and not oversized) on all types of devices.

Comment: The pixel doubling for retina was the issue and your suggestion resolved it.Good job, thanks :)